# ASP.Net throwing parser errors when I run the code under IIS, but works with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have created a new ASP web application for .NET 4.5 using Visual Studio 2013. When i run the project using visual studio (which launches IIS express) the site works fine. The project is stored in an IIS directory, so i tried to run it through IIS without having to run the project with VS and when i do this i get a parser error.

> Could not load type 'TestSite.Default'.

I created a new blank project and added a single web form called default. The namespace is TestShop. I don't see how this issue is happening since this is just a blank application.

I have tried building the project multiple times. It works fine when run through VS so there is nothing wrong with the code, but it doesnt appear to be correctly configured to work with IIS when inside a sub directory.

When running through VS the URL looks like this

```
http://localhost:55099/Default.aspx
```

When i run the project through IIS the url has nested subdirectories, which i think might be the cause, but i really dont know for sure.

```
http://localhost:888/testsites/TestSite/Default.aspx
```

I have an incredibly basic file. There is nothing inside of it, so there is a really small margin for error here.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestSite.Default" %>

It Works
```

The code behind file is just the default auto generated file.

```
namespace TestSite
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a parser error.

Comment: IIS is throwing it as a parser error Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestSite.Default'.

Comment: It this is running in a subdirectory you probably haven't set-up an Application Scope in IIS. Right-click the folder in IIS Manager and choose "Convert to Application".

Comment: Ah i didnt think of this. I have my parent website and that runs, i then have an admin portal in a sub directory of the main site. I tried converting this subdirectory to Application, but it didnt make the error go away